# Dropzone js uplaod 2 sizes of picture

Tags: dropzone.js

I haven't dive in to trying the library out because I am trying to find out if this is possible.

I want to have the client side create a thumbnail as well as optimize the orignal file for web use. So upload maybe a 30x30 or 50x50 thumbnail and then a full size image like 600x600 or 800x800 With the same post request. Then I will be able to provide the serve the photos directly from what was uploaded.

If this is possible, what would the thumbnail be, post file[1] and full image, size file[0]

Is it possible to set it up to allow multiple post request for multiple images where each request has both a thumbnail and a full size image?

Answer (score 0):

Is not a built in feature in dropzone but it is possible, but I think the easiest approach using dropzone would be to send the full image as a file, and the thumbnail as a text input field with the thumbnail base 64 encoded.

And yes you can configure dropzone to send an independent request for every image with one of this pairs per request.

Comment: Ok, I will start looking into it more now that it is possible, as well as base 64 encoding. Will I have to override some of the library functions to make it work right?

Comment: No need to overwrite.